# Pressing keys Alt / Alt + Tab ; even Ctrl + A sometimes resets the HTML form

Tags: javascript, dom, key, reset, alt

I have tried to prevent the default behavior, but for some reason, time to time I see that the form is reset (therefore re-submitted), once the ALT key is pressed. Testing system in the Brave, but checked and in the Chrome got the save behavior.
Has anybody had this problem, how to prevent this?
I will attach the code (javascript) that I tried to use for now. I hope I have formulated the question in right way, apologize if not (This is the first question I ask - so far I managed myself). Thank you!

```
const handleKeys = function (e) {
if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey || e.repeat) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); }}
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {handleKeys(e);});
```

Comment: You have to find when the form resets... *sometimes* and *time to time* is not helpful. Do not write code to fix an unknown issue.

Comment: `Enter` in an input field within a form will submit... Maybe that is your issue if you didn't know.

Comment: Enter key on keyboard is not pressed, and even if it would be, that also is checked in all the fields that can be submitted. 
I thought I can catch the key that is pressed on the keyboard on whole document /window and before it is used in action prevent its default. Maybe I was wrong.
Still idea about rechecking all input fields is good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Louys Patrice Bessette for giving a hint.

Solution:

1. The input field (search - by id searchBar) was focused on window load
   `window.addEventListener('load', function(e) { if (searchBar) {searchBar.focus();} });`
2. Input had following listener ():
   `if (searchBar) {searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {if (e.target.value.length > 0 && e.code === "Enter") {document.querySelector(searchForm).submit();}  });}`
3. Pressing "ALT" or "CTRL" key on keybord the input field got submitted (as it lost focus)
4. So I have changed code to following and now everything works (if the other keys are pressed the form is not submitted):

```
if (searchBar) {searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {if 
  if ((e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey)) {e.preventDefault(); searchBar.focus(); return;}
    else { 

if (e.target.value.length > 0 && e.code === "Enter") {document.querySelector(searchForm).submit();}  

if (e.target.value.length === 0 && (e.code === "Enter" || e.code === "Backspace" || e.code === "Delete")) {document.querySelector(searchForm).submit();}}
}
});}
```